# Parsing JSON data via a POST request in JS and C#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net

I'm using C# as my back end and want to make a JSON object/string request to my back end of C#.

I have C# code like so (for GET requests):

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true,
ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString = false)]
public static string GetOptionsServiceHttpGet(string variableId)
{
    // Do database stuff

    string retval = Serialize stuff/function goes here

    return retval;
}
```

The javascript front end code is this:

```
function Variable_Proxy() { }

       Variable_Proxy.GetVarOptionsHttpGet =
       function (variableId, successCallback, failureCallback) {
           $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               url: "file.aspx/GetOptionsServiceHttpGet?varId=\"" + variableId + "\",
               success: function (data) { successCallback(data); },
               error: function (data) { failureCallback(data); }
           });
       }
```

How do I do a post or whatever to get my JSON object to my back end on click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, if the data you are posting is a simple employee object you can do an AJAX POST as follows:

**C# backend:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for TestWebService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class TestWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public TestWebService () {
        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string GetPersonData(int id, Person objPerson) {
        return "You have submitted data with ID: " + id.ToString() + " Name: " + objPerson.Name + " and Email: " +  objPerson.Email;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public Employee CreateEmployee(int id, Person objPerson) {
        Employee objEmployee = new Employee();
        objEmployee.ID = id;
        objEmployee.Name = objPerson.Name;
        objEmployee.Email = objPerson.Email;
        return objEmployee;
    }

    public class Person{
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public string Email {get;set;}
    }

    public class Employee : Person {
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**jQuery front-end:**

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
   // create the json string
   var jsonData = JSON.stringify({
           'id': $("#txtID").val(),
            objPerson: {
                  'name': $("#txtName").val(),
                  'email': $("#txtEmail").val()
            }
   });

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/TestWebService.asmx/CreateEmployee",
      data: jsonData,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
             //alert the error if needed
             $("#result").html("Sorry there is an error: "   xhr.responseText);
      },
      success: function (responseData) {
             // show the response data from webservice. Note: the d represent the object property data passed by webservice. It can an object of properties or just single property
             $("#result").html("The id is " + responseData.d.ID + " And Name is " + responseData.d.Name + " And Email is " + responseData.d.Email);
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Cool what does the C# look like (+1 for the help)

Comment: No worries, if you find it helpful would you mind accepting it as an answer?

Comment: Yes I am. What do these lines mean:

Comment: WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

Comment: When creating a new webservice in Visual Studio, the IDE automatically adds the following line on top of your `TestWebService.cs` file: `[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]`
This attribute indicates that your webservice follows a given standard. The `WS-I` does not allow overloading.

Comment: Since webservices require unique namespaces so that they don't confuse each others schemas and whatever with each other, the attribute `WebService(Namespace = "tempuri.org/")]`  is there to enforce such integrity. A URL (domain, subdomain, subsubdomain, etc) is a clever identifier as it's "guaranteed" to be unique, and in most circumstances you've already got one.

Comment: Cool one more question, I haven't written many .net web services, but after it's processed can I do a Response.Redirect("toMyOutputPage.aspx")?

Comment: In general you can't do a `Response.Redirect` inside a webmethod. But you can try `Context.Response.StatusCode = 307; Context.Response.AddHeader("Location","toMyOutputPage.aspx");` just before the return statement. Read this [thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1953265.aspx?Response+Redirect+from+web+method+in+a+service+) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
 try
   {


       List<DataObject> DataList = new List<DataObject>();
        ...................

       return new { Result = "OK", Records = DataList };

  }  catch (Exception ex)  {

           return new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message };
  }
```